# Translate Production error on Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, debugging, locale, translate

In Laravel, how can i translate the error shown in production mode like "500 Internal Server Error", to other language (locale) ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be need custom error view, for implemention you need to create `500.blade.php` in errors folder of views. and then design it by your need. But remember that server errors like 500 wont render views. For that you may try to edit `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`'s render function to this :

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {


   // 404 page when a model is not found
if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
    return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
}

if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
} else {
    // Custom error 500 view on production
    if (app()->environment() == 'production') {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
} 

}
```

Share if this helps you, it didnt tested by me. But it should work

**Update**

Above code may show 500 for validation errors, so check out this one

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) {
   $exception = \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException::create($e);
   $statusCode = $exception->getStatusCode($exception);

   if (env('APP_DEBUG') == FALSE && $statusCode == 500 && $e instanceof ValidationException != TRUE) {
      return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
   } else {
      return parent::render($request, $e);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally, all the error pages render text with i18n support.

Keep in mind that for further customization other than translating messages, you can still publish the error views and customize them to suit your needs with this artisan command:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

You should refer to this paragraph about [localization using translation strings as keys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys) to create the required json files.
The keys you need to override are defined in the default blade error pages you can find on [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views)

Imagine you want to override the 500 error message.
Find all the usages of the `__` (double underscore) function in the `500.blade.php` file as well as in the layout files.

The provided parameter would become the key you will use to override the message in the json file.

#### Example

For instance, given the `500.blade.php` file contents:

```php
@extends('errors::minimal')

@section('title', __('Server Error'))
@section('code', '500')
@section('message', __('Server Error'))
```

The corresponding json translation file could be defined as:

```js
{
    "Server Error": "This is my custom message that will override the default one!"
}
```

If you still have doubts, just ask for clarifications in the comments.